# Pin search bar to Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to pin the search bar/search&replace bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to the window. Because now, if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, my search bar disappears.

For example when having search bar + multi-line cursors active and when I want to deactivate multi-line cursors using my keyboard (I know a mouse click deactivates multi-line cursors too), I click on <kbd>Esc</kbd>. But <kbd>Esc</kbd> deactivates both (search bar + multi-line cursors)

I hope you understand what I mean.

**Edit**:

There is one thing that I'm asking myself a lot of times. I can make the search bar active by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but after I search I want to go back to edit my file (I want to go out of my search bar and go to the place where I found what I searched) This is again possible with mouse click but i want to do it with my keyboard. (something like tab out of the search field). Anyone who knows there is a key binding for this?
--> I found I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for this but it selects all occurences. to disable the selections I just move with my arrow keys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ST2 you can just edit/remove default key binding (as I remember) for this:

```
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "hide_panel", "args": {"cancel": true},
  "context":
  [
    { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
  ]
},
```

ST3 doesn't allow you to edit default bindings so I was able only to reorder <kbd>Esc</kbd> button behavior when panel is visible: first press deactivates multi-line cursors, and the second press hides a search panel. If no multi-line cursors active then <kbd>Esc</kbd> only hides a search panel.

Try to add these lines to the User's key bindings file:

```
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "single_selection", "context":
  [
    { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": 1 }
  ]
},
```

Hope this will help.

**EDIT**: Fixed lines to add

Comment: Thanks, I completely removed the `hide_panel` binding for `ESC` so my search bar never goes away.

Comment: @Ozkan As your problem has been solved, it'd be a good idea to mark phts' answer as accepted.